# Como borrar palabra por palabra de un edit text en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, botón, edittext, funcion

Hola ando con una duda de dias, ando tratando de borrar una palabras en edit text tengo un boton llamado "Borrar" quiero que el boton haga la funcion de borrar pero no todo el contenido del edittext si no por partes ejemplo: tengo dos palabras una hola y otra adios que el boton borrar al presionar el boton primero borre el adios y luego presionando el boton de borrar nuevamente borre el hola asi haciendo que quede limpio el campo de edittext. es una pregunta bantante facil de responder espero que me puedan ayudar se los agradeceria.

```
    Package com.codetr.tanwir.textandlanguageuseseñas;
   
 public class signosdeseñas extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private EditText et1;
        private ImageView hola, adios;
        private Button borrar;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate((savedInstanceState));
            setContentView(R.layout.señas);
    
            hola = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hola);
            adios = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.adios);
            borrar = (button) findViewById(R.id.borrar);
            curr = "";

 borrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr =  "" ;
                    displayOne();
    
                }
            });  
  
     hola.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr = curr + "hola " ;
                    displayOne();
                }
            });
    
     adios.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    curr = curr + "adios " ;
                    displayOne();
                }
            });public void displayOne(){

            et1.setText(curr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución posible es programar un método borrarPalabra() que detecte el índice o posición del último carácter de espacio " " en el texto y elimine la subcadena que exista después de ese índice. Naturalmente conviene hacer que el método controle los casos en que ya no existe ningún texto en el campo de texto (text.isEmpty()) y muestre un mensaje apropiado al usuario, en lugar de intentar la operación de borrar:

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.holamundo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et1;
    private Button btnBorrarPalabra;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate((savedInstanceState));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        btnBorrarPalabra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBorrarPalabra);

        btnBorrarPalabra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                borrarPalabra();
            }
        });
    }

    private void borrarPalabra() {
        String text = et1.getText().toString().trim();

        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "No hay más palabras en el campo de texto",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            return;
        }

        int lastIndex = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
        if (lastIndex != -1) {
            et1.setText(text.substring(0, lastIndex));
        } else {
            et1.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Escriba un texto aquí"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBorrarPalabra"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Borrar palabra"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Algunos elementos como las vistas ImageView o el método displayOne() presentes en tu código no parecían directamente relacionados con los requisitos del ejercicio que planteas, y por esta razón he prescindido de ellos.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder Alejandro y gracias por la entrega que haces a la comunidad se te agradece y mucho! cuando borro borra palabra por palabra pero en si cuando asigno otra se junta la palabra anterior que se borro con anterioridad como podria modificarlo? Gracias! Gracias!

Comment: Deduzco que quieres poner en juego otro método que "asigna" nuevas palabras al EditText programáticamente. Para mantener un espacio antes de las palabras nuevas que se añadan, al código más arriba solo necesitas añadirle en el bloque if lo siguiente:

if (lastIndex != -1) {
            et1.setText(text.substring(0, lastIndex));
            et1.append(" ");

Comment: Hola alejandro se repite dos veces si presiono el boton hola, nuevamente sera que es por boton? saludos!